# What is the literary device where a word holds two meanings in a phrase?

Tags: literary-device

For example,

He showed the strength of his arms and his heart when he pushed the fallen horse out of the mud slide.

Comment: @TannerSwett that's it. I always forget it for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how the strength of his muscles, the arms and the heart, are two very different things. Perhaps it is the strength of his feelings for the horse, a living thing - assuming the horse was alive after the slide, that is being referenced.

The usage can be called a semantic syllepsis, or zeugma based on answers to similar questions.

Comment: Strength of one's heart is a case of figurative language. He "had the heart to save the horse"